# Vcsrepo fails with gitlab

Tags: puppet, gitlab

I want to pull some gitlab repositories using vcsrepo but for some reason it fails to execute.

```
vcsrepo { "/tmp/repo/update":
 ensure => present,
 provider => git,
 source => "git@gitlab:${git_url}",
 user => 'update',
}
```

The ssh key belongs to the user update, the source doesn't work with or without 'git@'

The error:

> err:
>   /Stage[main]//Node[xxx]/Git::Add_git[webhooks]/Vcsrepo[/tmp/webhooks/update]/ensure:
>   change from absent to present failed: Could not set 'present on
>   ensure: undefined method `execute' for Puppet::Util::Execution:Module
>   at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-2/modules-0/git/manifests/init.pp:54

What did I do wrong?

Comment: help please! :(

Comment: Having same issue, just put a bounty on this.

Comment: Which version of puppet are you using?

Comment: Also, your error is noting a resource "Vcsrepo[/tmp/webhooks/update]", but you pasted the resource "/tmp/repo/update". Can you show the definition for /tmp/webhooks/update please?

Comment: I use a defined type, which adds multiple repositories to my system. It should be ${repo} and the name of the repo is automatically the name of the subfolder. I use Puppet 2.7

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of vcsrepo (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo) in Puppet 2.7, that might be the reason why it's not working. According to the forge page, it requires Puppet 3.x.

Comment: Then it shouldn't work with Git or SVN though, but I have no problems checking such repos out.

Comment: Are these the only resources for which you use the user parameter? Could the others be using the default user (= the user as which puppet runs?). Reason I'm asking is that it looks to me the code only triggers the 'execute' when the user parameter is used. Check https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/vcsrepo/git.rb line 433.

Comment: This worked for me; added the puppetlabs repository and used the latest version instead of the version that came bundled with epel.

Comment: I use two different defined types for SVN and Gitlab, I added the 'user' variable to the Gitlab type because I want to check out the repo with a certain SSH user. Without the 'user' variable I get the following error:

Comment: err: /Stage[main]//Node[xxx]/Git::Add_git[webhooks]/Vcsrepo[/tmp/webhooks/update]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/git clone gitlab://xxx/gitlab-webhooks.git /tmp/webhooks/update' returned 128: Cloning into '/tmp/webhooks/update'...
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'gitlab'